# SymPy nonlinsolve NameError:

Tags: python, sympy, nameerror

I get a NameError when using SymPy nonlinsolve. After reading a lot of posts I think can be related to type and/or syntax, but I cannot find the exact cause, I just installed sympy a few days ago and my python version is Python 3.5.3 (default, Jan 19 2017, 14:11:04) 
[GCC 6.3.0 20170118] on linux
thanks in advance
Vilbjorg

```
# Python 3 script , using SymPy library, parametrizatrion of the 3-sphere and rotations using quaternion multiplication
# python3 three_sphere.py
from sympy import *

def qmul(x0, x1, x2, x3, y0, y1, y2, y3):

    z0 = x0*y0 - x1*y1 - x2*y2 - x3*y3
    z1 = x0*y1 + x1*y0 + x2*y3 - x3*y2
    z2 = x0*y2 - x1*y3 + x2*y0 + x3*y1
    z3 = x0*y3 + x1*y2 - x2*y1 + x3*y0
    return z0, z1, z2, z3


r1, s1, t1, r2, s2, t2 = symbols('r1, s1, t1, r2, s2, t2')
a0 = 2*r1/(1 + r1*r1 + s1*s1 + t1*t1)
a1 = 2*s1/(1 + r1*r1 + s1*s1 + t1*t1)
a2 = 2*t1/(1 + r1*r1 + s1*s1 + t1*t1)
a3 = (1 - r1*r1 - s1*s1 - t1*t1)/(1 + r1*r1 + s1*s1 + t1*t1)

b0 = 2*r2/(1 + r2*r2 + s2*s2 + t2*t2)
b1 = 2*s2/(1 + r2*r2 + s2*s2 + t2*t2)
b2 = 2*t2/(1 + r2*r2 + s2*s2 + t2*t2)
b3 = (1 - r2*r2 - s2*s2 - t2*t2)/(1 + r2*r2 + s2*s2 + t2*t2)

c0, c1, c2, c3 = qmul(a0, a1, a2, a3, b0, b1, b2, b3)

c0 = simplify(c0)
c1 = simplify(c1)
c2 = simplify(c2)
c3 = simplify(c3)

print(c0)
print("  ")
print(c1)
print("  ")
print(c2)
print("  ")
print(c3)
print("  ")
print("  ")

r3, s3, t3 = symbols('r3, s3, t3')
q0 = 2*r3/(1 + r3*r3 + s3*s3 + t3*t3)
q1 = 2*s3/(1 + r3*r3 + s3*s3 + t3*t3)
q2 = 2*t3/(1 + r3*r3 + s3*s3 + t3*t3)
q3 = (1 - r3*r3 - s3*s3 - t3*t3)/(1 + r3*r3 + s3*s3 + t3*t3)


#possibly syntax error here which causes NameError ??
soln = nonlinsolve([q0-c0, q1-c1, q2-c2, q3-c3], (r3, s3, t3))
# the idea is to have 4 equations : q0=c0, q1=c1. q2=c2. q3=c3 ; and solve for r3, s3 and t3 in terms of r1, s1, t1, r2, s2, t2
print(soln)

# http://docs.sympy.org/dev/tutorial/solvers.html
```

Answer (score 4):

You are using a version of SymPy which does not have `nonlinsolve`. One way to fix this is to update SymPy (versions starting with 1.1 have it).  The other is to replace `nonlinsolve` with `solve`.

Unfortunately, neither will produce a solution of your system.  This is because in general, a system of several algebraic equations has no explicit solution, unless you are really lucky. So neither  `nonlinsolve` nor `solve` get anywhere with it, despite trying for a long time.

Comment: Tanks very much, indeed 'nonlinsolve' seems not present at all in the sympy I got here (version 1.0.3) This particular problem perhaps needs some human tricks applied before it can be solved. Now using 'solve' the computer is still working hard at it while writing. Not sure it will arrive at a conclusion.